# Detect the component which is slowing my UI

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application and I would like to be able to know my components needs in refresh :

My page is working fine but when I add this piece of code :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="57" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="57" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2,2,2" x:Name="textBlock1" Text="-" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="textBlock2" Text="-" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="textBlock3" Text="-" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="textBlock4" Text="-" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="textBlock5" Text="-" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="textBlock6" Text="-" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="text_home" Text="1" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Margin="2,2,2,2" Grid.Column="4" Name="text_away" Text="2" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />


        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="valeur_home_1" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="valeur_home_2" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="valeur_home_3" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="valeur_home_4" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="valeur_home_5" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="valeur_home_6" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" />

        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="valeur_away_1" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="valeur_away_2" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="valeur_away_3" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="valeur_away_4" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="valeur_away_5" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="6" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="valeur_away_6" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" />

        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="nom_home_1" Text="Nom du Joueur" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="nom_home_2" Text="Nom du Joueur" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="nom_home_3" Text="Nom du Joueur" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="nom_home_4" Text="Nom du Joueur" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="nom_home_5" Text="Nom du Joueur" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="nom_home_6" Text="Nom du Joueur" TextAlignment="Center" />

        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="nom_away_1" Text="Nom du Joueur" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="nom_away_2" Text="Nom du Joueur" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="nom_away_3" Text="Nom du Joueur" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="nom_away_4" Text="Nom du Joueur" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="nom_away_5" Text="Nom du Joueur" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="6" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="nom_away_6" Text="Nom du Joueur" TextAlignment="Center" />

        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Margin="2" Name="my_stand" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}" Margin="2" Name="my_stand_away" Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3" />
    </Grid>
```

it becomes really really slow. My page is doing real time simulations and I need sometimes (every 15sec) to refresh these textblocks.
I can't understand why this is becoming slow, I mean I have with my simulation some charts or tables and when I choose to display the page with the charts it works fine and when I want to display the page with the textblocks it is really really slow.

Is there a way to analyze a WPF application and detect which UI component is using the most resources ? I've tried instrumentation but, has expected, it only says Application.Run is critical.

Comment: Show piece of code where you do refreshing. Maybe there are expensive calls.

Comment: Are you loading the data asynchronously and not on the GUI thread?

Comment: Is it still slow if you remove this from each textblock 'Style="{StaticResource StyleTextes}"'?

Comment: I could try to load my data async but it is slow even when I don't refresh my data, just by switching to this page. I've removed the styles and it's the same. I really don't understand. Even Snoop has troubles to load.

Comment: In fact the UI is slow even when I pause my simulation. I just have to switch to this page and it's slow (I can see it with mouseovers)

Answer (score -1):

Visual studio have a debugging tool (alt+F2 in VS2015)

select "performance assistant" or "using UC" (or another) and "start"

you can see on it the most functions cost etc ...

Comment: This does not answer the question. Add it as a comment to the question instead

Comment: "need sometimes (every 15sec) to refresh these textblocks. I can't understand why this is becoming slow", with debugging tool you can see the most costly functions. You can rewind the stack too. so find the problem
nope ?

Comment: Sorry, but i dont understand, this is not juste à debugger, this is a diagnose tool, he's starting in the start and when you close your app, that show you any costly function and you can move on the stack. I'm sur we can find this element with this tool, so i dont understand your comments or maybe i'm not full understand the question.